# Slack Bolt Python Bot User and User OAuth Tokens

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

The method to initialize the slack app through slack bolt python is

```
app = App(token = SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, signing_secret = SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET)
```

In this case, the app only has bot token scopes.

What about slack apps that require both bot token scopes and user token scopes? Do create two app instances? How do I initialise an app that has both scopes? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have the slack app created through your account and install the slack app to your workspace, you'll be able to get the user token from the OAuth section in the Slack App dashboard. However, the above is only applicable for single user.

If you want your app to be used in multiple workspaces. You can set up the OAuth flow which is supported by the `slack-bolt` framework with user and bot token scopes and can access the values in your app using `context.bot_token` and `context.user_token`. Read more [here](https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/oauth/).

Below is a basic example on setting up the OAuth flow using `slack-bolt` and `Flask`

```
import os
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.oauth.oauth_settings import OAuthSettings
from slack_sdk.oauth.installation_store.file import FileInstallationStore
from slack_sdk.oauth.state_store.file import FileOAuthStateStore
from slack_bolt.adapter.flask import SlackRequestHandler
from flask import Flask, request

# oauth settings with all required parameters
oauth_settings = OAuthSettings(
    client_id = os.getenv("SLACK_CLIENT_ID"),
    scopes = ["commands","files:read","users:read","users:read.email","chat:write"],
    user_scopes = ["files:read"],
    redirect_uri = None,
    install_page_rendering_enabled = False,
    install_path = "/slack/install",
    redirect_uri_path = "/slack/oauth_redirect",
    installation_store = FileInstallationStore(base_dir="./data/installations"),
    state_store = FileOAuthStateStore(expiration_seconds=600, base_dir="./data/states")
)

# Initializes your app
app = App(
    signing_secret=os.getenv("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET"),
    oauth_settings=oauth_settings
)

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
handler = SlackRequestHandler(app)

# endpoint for handling all slack events
@flask_app.route("/slack/events", methods=["POST"])
def slack_events():
    return handler.handle(request)

# endpoint for handling app install
@flask_app.route("/slack/install", methods=["GET"])
def install():
    return handler.handle(request)

# for oauth redirect
@flask_app.route("/slack/oauth_redirect", methods=["GET"])
def oauth_redirect():
    return handler.handle(request)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  flask_app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple tokens in a Slack app, you can pass the token in the client call.

For example:

```
// Post a message to a channel

await client.chat.postMessage({

    token: desiredToken,

    channel: channelID,

    text: `You approved the message with the value ${payload.value}`

});
```

So you won't need to initialize two different apps. Instead, you'll need to cache the token as an environment variable, or fetch it from your auth store when you need it, and add it to your client call.

As events and requests sent to your app are not associated with a specific token, they're associated with a specific permission scope and event subscription: https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api

Installing an app with a scope will generate an appropriate token, but that token isn't required for receiving an event or setting up the Event Request URL. That token is for calling API methods which also require the same scope. Only the scope is required for setting events with your app. A token can also be associated with many scopes.

For context, some API methods require a specific scope, such as `chat.postMessage` requires a `chat:write` scope. The scopes tell Slack which permissions your app should have, and will grant your app a Token for calling the API. Some scopes may be required for calling an API method and listening to an event. However, events require scopes to function and not tokens.

Example:

The `user_change` event requires the `users:read` scope and the event subscription.

The `users.info` API method also requires the `users:read` scope but you must call this method with a token.