# Slack API: URL Verification Request Error (404 or bad gateway) using ngrok

Tags: python, slack, ngrok, image-classification

I am building a slack bot with python that is supposed to classify sent images, check whether they are appropriate or not and then delete them in the channel. The app is installed in my workplace, it is added as integration but I can not add it as a separate user.

I used ngrok and am having trouble verifying the URL. Adding /slack/events to the URL the verification worked for the verification but there are still no messages being classified. The server keeps saying "Waiting to receive a response from your server (2525 minutes so far)." when posting an image file via postman. Sending a picture in the channel just I tried stripping the code to its bare-bones and build a bot that answers "hello world" to all messages in the channel but even that didn't work. I really don't know what I am missing, Chat GPT is only going in circles at this point.
Here is the code (this version is responding with a text "Oh, Pictures!" as confirmation that it has received an image, but that doesn't work either)

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import requests
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.flask import SlackRequestHandler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as preprocessing
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Get your OAuth
slack_token = os.environ.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN')
slack_signing_secret = os.environ.get('SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET')

# Create a Bolt for Python app using the token and signing secret
app = App(token=slack_token, signing_secret=slack_signing_secret)

# Initialize the Slack request handler with your Bolt app
handler = SlackRequestHandler(app)

# Load the model
model= load_model(r'./directory/to/model.h5')

# Function to classify an image
def classify_image(image_url):
    """
    Download an image from the given URL, preprocess it and predict its class using the classifier model
    """
    # Download the image
    response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    response.raise_for_status()
    img = Image.open(response.raw)

    # Preprocess the image
    test_image = img.resize((224, 224))
    test_image = preprocessing.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = test_image / 255.0
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)

    # Predict the class of the image
    class_names = ['ok', 'not_ok']
    predictions = henrietta.predict(test_image)
    scores = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions[0])
    scores = scores.numpy()
    image_class = class_names[np.argmax(scores)]

    return image_class

# When a message is posted in the channel
@app.message('')
def handle_message(message, say):
    # If the message contains a file
    if 'files' in message:
        # Loop through all the files
        for file in message['files']:
            # If the file is an image
            if file['mimetype'].startswith('image/'):
                # Post a confirmation text
                say({"text": "Oh, pictures!"})

                # Classify the image
                image_class = classify_image(file['url_private_download'])

                # If the image is inappropriate
                if image_class == 'not_ok':
                    # Delete the original message
                    say({
                        "text": "An inappropriate image was removed. Here's a cute one instead!",
                        "attachments": [
                            {
                                "fallback": "Cute image",
                                "image_url": "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3758221.jpg"
                            }
                        ]
                    })

# Start your app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.start(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", <port_number>)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which works

```
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.flask import SlackRequestHandler
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()  # load variables from .env
import random

app = App()

def classify_image(image_url):
    #do processing here
    class_names = ['ok', 'not_ok']
    return random.choice(class_names)

@app.event("message")
def handle_message(message, client, body, say):
    if 'files' in message:
        for file in message['files']:
            if file['mimetype'].startswith('image/'):
                image_class = classify_image(file['url_private_download'])
                if image_class == 'not_ok':
                    channel_id = body["event"]["channel"]
                    timestamp = body["event"]["ts"]
                    client.chat_delete(token = "{USER_TOKEN_HERE}", channel=channel_id, ts=timestamp)
                    say({
                        "text": "An inappropriate image was removed. Here's a cute one instead!",
                        "attachments": [
                            {
                                "fallback": "Cute image",
                                "image_url": "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/3758221.jpg"
                            }
                        ]
                    })


from flask import Flask, request

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
handler = SlackRequestHandler(app)


@flask_app.route("/slack/events", methods=["POST"])
def slack_events():
    return handler.handle(request)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(debug = True, port = 8080)
```

Created this by modifying the minimal example from the framework's [github example.](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/blob/main/examples/flask/app.py)

Also stripped out the part where you process the image and returned a random value each time.

I'm using the `client.chat_delete` method to delete the message. Please note that this requires the user token rather than the bot token. When using on a single workspace, you can find the user token by going into OAuth & Permissions section in your slack app settings.

If you want to integrate this app to multiple workspace and users, you'll need to setup OAuth and then you'll be able to access the tokens in your app context. See another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75780929/14368944) written by me which explains the same.